Is it necessary to convert my urdf file to an sdf file to run on gazebo?
I am trying to launch my robot model on gazebo after implementing ultrasonic sensor plugins. It was working just fine but now I am getting a parsing error on launch, Worse, the check urdf in ros is parsing them successfully while the model itself is not spawning in gazebo. How do I resolve this? Online some ppl are suggesting the use of gz to convert urdf to sdf to run it. It was launching just fine before plugins were implemented so I do not think its necessary at all.
I tried launching my robot model with ultrasonic sensors on gazebo11 using RoS2 Humble.
